# Make duplicate of all words in string

Tags: c, string

I need to make duplicate of all words in string, and a space should be inserted between repeated words.

*Definition of word:*
array of characters separated by: digits, period, comma, space, tab, or newline. So a word can contain every character besides these mentioned.

EXAMPLES:

```
char str[]="one.two three";
char str[]="!4A7+++3---";
```

OUTPUT:

```
"one one.two two three three"
"! !4A A7+++ +++3--- ---"
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *make_duplicate(char *str) {
  int i = 1;
  char *s = str;
  while (*s != '\0') {
    if (*str == 48 || *str == 49 || *str == 50 || *str == 51 || *str == 52 ||
        *str == 53 || *str == 54 || *str == 55 || *str == 56 || *str == 57 ||
        *str == 44 || *str == 46 || *str == 9 || *str == 10 || *str == 32)
      i++;
    s++;
  }
  return str;
}
int main() {
  char str[]="one.two three";
  // char str[]="!4A7+++3---";
  printf("%s", make_duplicate(str));
  return 0;
}
```

Numbers in my code are ASCII values of characters that cannot be part of word.

In my code I find how many words are in string. How could I after that make that number of duplicates in string?

- Note: is not allowed to use functions from the `string.h`, `stdlib.h` libraries, as well as the `sprintf` and `sscanf` functions from the stdio.h library. It is not allowed to create auxiliary strings or strings.

Comment: Is the goal to only create the output or to return a string containing the duplicates. If you intend to return a string containing the duplicates then you're going to need to create an auxiliary string or allocate more memory.

Comment: There is only one string, function should make duplicates of all words from that string, put them inside that string, and return the pointer to the beginning of that string.

Comment: `char str[]="one.two three";` does not allocate enough space to add anything to this string.

Comment: `i` counts how many words are in string, and I think that `str` points to the beginning of string because program prints the same string

Comment: This is in rough shape.  Looks like a bunch of fundamentals need to be revisited.  Not sure if you understand what `char *s = str;` does.  Not sure if you realize that `str` does not change its value during the loop.  Not sure if you realize that the bytes pointed to by str never change.  Not sure if you realize that `i` is never used for anything.  Not sure if you realize you return the input string unmodified.  Not sure if you realize that the only thing you accomplished is to not hang if you have a null-terminated string.

Comment: I understand everything you mentioned. However, I don't have any idea how to solve this.

Comment: what would be your algorithm for solving this?

Comment: Rather than exaggerate with "I don't have any idea how to solve this.", be specific.

Comment: well I'm beginner, every algorithm I would think in my head would be hard for me to implement, because strings problems are the hardest for me

Comment: If "Definition of word: array of characters separated by: digits, period, comma, space, tab, or newline," shouldn't "one.two three" be parsed as "one two three"? (Which you can do in-place and with `O(1)` extra memory.) Is there some additional rule that says "." is ⨉?

Comment: @Neil word is everything besides mentioned characters

Comment: I don't see how "one.two three" -> "one one.two two three three"; the string is not topologically equivalent to the first, there are delimiters in the string. Likely I am misunderstanding the question.

Comment: "one" found -> added to orginal -> "one one.two three" -> "two" found -> "one one.two  two three" -> "three" found -> "one one.two two three three"

Comment: it's a little bit tricky

Comment: Thanks for explaining: like tail-recursion, [one, [one.two three, [two, [two three, [three]]]]]. It is a little bit tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot use any auxiliary string, I guess you are supposed to modify the string argument in place, assuming the array is long enough. Here is a simple solution that meets the constraints:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isdelim(char c) {
    switch (c) {
      case '\0':
      case '.':  case ',':  case ' ':  case '\t':  case '\n':
      case '0':  case '1':  case '2':  case '3':   case '4':
      case '5':  case '6':  case '7':  case '8':   case '9':
        return 1;
      default:
        return 0;
    }
}

// duplicates words, assuming str is long enough
char *make_duplicate(char *str) {
    size_t delta = 0;
    char *p = str;
    char *dest;
    char *wptr = NULL;

    for (;;) {
        if (isdelim(*p)) {   // delimiter found
            if (wptr) {      // add duplicated word length
                delta += 1 + p - wptr;
                wptr = NULL;
            }
        } else {
            if (!wptr) {     // not a delim; now we're in a word
                wptr = p;
            }
        }
        if (*p++ == '\0')
            break;
    }
    if (delta > 0) {
        while (p > str) {    // shift string to make space for dups
            p--;
            p[delta] = *p;
        }
        dest = str;
        p = str + delta;
        //wptr = NULL;         // wptr is NULL already
        while (dest < p) {
            if (isdelim(*p)) {        // delimiter found
                if (wptr) {           // duplicate a word
                    *dest++ = ' ';    // separate word with space
                    while (wptr < p)  // duplicate the last word
                        *dest++ = *wptr++;
                    wptr = NULL;
                }
            } else {
                if (!wptr) {    // not a delim; now we're in a word
                    wptr = p;
                }
            }
            *dest++ = *p++;
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char str1[32] = "one.two three";
    char str2[32] = "!4A7+++3---";

    printf("%s\n", make_duplicate(str1));
    printf("%s\n", make_duplicate(str2));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
one one.two two three three
! !4A A7+++ +++3--- ---
```

Comment: is buffer considered to be auxiliary string?

Comment: @codproe: indeed a buffer is an array, which is probably restricted.  I amended the answer with a solution whereby the string argument is modified in place, assuming the array is long enough.

Comment: return modified string

Comment: you always make it simple and efficient

Comment: If input array is sufficiently large, you can move the contents to second half of the buffer & read from there to populate from the beginning.

Comment: @SparKot: that's exactly what I do, but I only move the contents by the amount of extra bytes `delta` that will be inserted. I assume the array is large enough for the result, but it does not have to be larger than that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a look-up table for word-delimiters.
2. Use look-up table to decide whether to duplicate a word or not.
3. Constraints :

   - signature `char* make_duplicate (char*);` is fixed.
   - no axillary strings are allowed, for making copies & generating output.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int dlt[256] = {0};

static inline int strLen (char* const str)
{
    int slen = 0;
    while (str[slen++]);
    return slen;
}

char* make_duplicate (char* str) {
    int slen = strLen (str);

    //str buffer has sufficient spare memory
    for (char* ap = str, *zp = str + slen + 1; ;) {
        *zp = *ap++;
        if ('\0' == *zp++) break;
    }

    char* aptr = NULL;
    char* zptr = str + slen + 1;
    char* dptr = str;

    while (1) {
        if (dlt[(unsigned char) *zptr]) {  // delimiter found
            if (aptr) {                     // there is a word
                *dptr++ = ' ';              // separate word with space
                while (aptr < zptr)         // duplicate the last word
                    *dptr++ = *aptr++;
                aptr = NULL;
            }
        } else if (!aptr) //not a delim; now we're in a word
            aptr = zptr;
        *dptr++ = *zptr;
        if ('\0' == *zptr++) break;
    }
    return str;
}


int main ()
{
    // word delimiters (digits, period, comma, space, tab, or newline)
    char word_delims[] = "0123456789., \t\n";
    dlt[0] = 1; // to cover nulchar
    for (int dc = 0; word_delims[dc] != '\0'; ++dc)
        dlt[ (unsigned char) word_delims[dc]] = 1;

#define INPUT_STRINGS   5   // one place to decide how many inputs
    char str[INPUT_STRINGS][128] = {"one.two three",
                                "!4A7+++3---",
                                "0123456789., \t\n",
                                "TheOnlyString",
                                "A"
                               };
    for (int si = 0; si < INPUT_STRINGS; ++si) {
        printf ("\nOriginal :\t[%s]\n", str[si]);
        printf ("Repeated Words:\t[%s]\n", make_duplicate (str[si]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, could you please make one modification? Function `make_duplicate` can only accept one parameter, which is string `str`

Comment: I have one problem, dynamical allocation is not allowed, could you please modify this without dynamical allocation?

Comment: A function takes a string & returns a bloated string without `extra` memory allocation is not possible. But you can print the output right away in the `make_duplicate()` call  one character at a time instead of storing in `dupe` string.

Comment: function `make_duplicate()` must return pointer to the beginning of string, I cannot print inside it, is there any way to make that?

Comment: Where is this problem/exercise from?

Comment: from my Introduction to Programming course, one of our assignments

Comment: Again, you can use a `static` array with sufficient array size. Or a global variable, in which case returning a string becomes redundant.

Comment: thank you very much, `static char dupe[10000];` worked

Comment: `dlt[ (int) *zptr]` invokes undefined behavior on negative `char` values on systems where `char` is signed by default. You should write `dlt[(unsigned char)*zptr]`.  The explicit cast `(int)*zptr` is a counterproductive way to silence the compiler warning.

Comment: `#include <malloc.h>` is non-standard.

Comment: `static char dupe[10000];` is auxiliary array, which is not allowed by the task setting